# How to get colour from in jquery slider on pick of a colour box

Tags: jquery, html, slider, jquery-ui-slider

```js
$('.StandardColor').click(function() {
         
        var SelectedCol = $('.StandardColor').attr(data - color);
         
        alert(SelectedCol)
        FillScrollColor(SelectedCol)
         
      });

      function FillScrollColor(SelectedColor) {
        var rgb = hexToRgbA(SelectedColor);

        $('#range_4').css({
          'background': 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(2, 1, 2, 1) 0%,' + rgb + '100%)'
        })
      }


      $("#range_4").slider({
        range: "min",
        max: 100,
        value: 50,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
          // How to pick the color!!
        }
      });


      function hexToRgbA(hex) {
        var c;
        if (/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)) {
          c = hex.substring(1).split('');
          if (c.length == 3) {
            c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
          }
          c = '0x' + c.join('');
          return 'rgba(' + [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255].join(',') + ',1)';
        }
        throw new Error('Bad Hex');
      }
```

```css
.color {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colors_range_row {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#range_4 {
  height: 12px;
  width: 95%;
  background: rgba(2, 1, 2, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(2, 1, 2, 1) 0%, rgba(103, 56, 111, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(2, 1, 2, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(103, 56, 111, 1)));
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#020102', endColorstr='#67386f', GradientType=1);
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/2.0.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="row">


  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #000" data-color="000"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #4a4a4a" data-color="4a4a4a"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #417505" data-color="417505"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #4a90e2" data-color="4a90e2"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #8a4ebf" data-color="8a4ebf"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #c0202a" data-color="c0202a"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #f5a623" data-color="f5a623"></span>
  <span class="color StandardColor" style="background: #f8e71c" data-color="f8e71c"></span>
  <span class="color  StandardColor empty" data-color="ffffff"></span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="colors_range_row">
  <div id="range_4" class="range"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I am trying to achieve the following

1. user can select any colour from a given range
2. On selecting (clicking) colour, slider gets feel with respective colour (dark to light)
3. if user slide the slider, respective box under slider get's filled with respective pointed colour

*As shown in the following image*

[image]

So kindly guide me how can I do the same.

Following is my code for the same.

```
<div class="colors_range_row">
    <div id="range_4" class="range"></div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>

<script>

    $('.colorBox').click(function () {          
      var SelectedCol = $('.StandardColor').attr('data-color');
     FillScrollColor(SelectedCol)
    });

    function FillScrollColor(SelectedColor) {
            var rgb = hexToRgbA(SelectedColor);

            $('#range_4').css({ 'background': 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(2, 1, 2, 1) 0%,' + rgb + '100%)' })
        }


$("#range_4").slider({
        range: "min",
        max: 100,
        value: 50,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            // How to pick the color!!
        }
      });

</script>
```

And I am lost on how to pick colour from the slider. ??

Comment: Can you provide more of the html for your demo so I can simulate it

Comment: Hope it will help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have come up with the following solution,

May be helpful to some in future.

- On click of Color, box has added respectively colour shades to range slider

  function makeTableRowColorsForIp(colors, displayType) {

  ```
         var tableRow = "<div class=\"wrapper\">";
              for (var i = colors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {        

                      if (displayType == "colors") { // make a row of colors
                          tableRow += "<div class=\"colro_set_IP\" data-ColorVal =\""+ colors[i].toString(16) +"\" style=\"background-color:" + "#" + colors[i].toString(16) + "\";></div>";
                          document.querySelector('.simple_barForIP').innerHTML = tableRow;
                      }
                       colors[i].toString(16).toUpperCase() + "</div>";

                  }
              tableRow += "</div>";
              return tableRow;
          }






  $(".StandardColor").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var parsedColorsArray = parseColorValues($("#hexValOfColorSelectedIP").val());
            if (parsedColorsArray !== null) {                   var colorDisplayRows = []; colors to display
                var tableRowCounter = 0;


                for (var i = 0; i < parsedColorsArray.length; i++) { 
                    var calculatedShades = calculateShades(parsedColorsArray[i]);
                    colorDisplayRows[tableRowCounter] = makeTableRowColorsForIp(calculatedShades, "colors");
                    tableRowCounter++;
                    colorDisplayRows[tableRowCounter] = makeTableRowColorsForIp(calculatedShades, "RGBValues");
                    tableRowCounter++;
                } 

            }
            return false;
        });
  ```

var slider = new Slider('#ex1ForIP', {
        formatter: function (value) {
            tintLenght = $('#simple_barForIP').find('.colro_set_IP').length;

var RangValue = value;
        //console.log(value.html());

```
    if (RangValue) {                
        var shadeColor = $('.colro_set_IP').eq(RangValue).attr('data-ColorVal');

        if (RangValue == 11) {
            $('.range-slider-IP .slider.slider-horizontal .slider-handle').css('margin-left', '-9.09091%');
        }
        else {
            $('.range-slider-IP .slider.slider-horizontal .slider-handle').css('margin-left', '0');
        }
    }
    SetBorderColor(shadeColor);
    return 'Current value: ' + value + shadeColor;
}
```

});